# show only duplicate records from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I did query for show data from to tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID AS postid, t2.meta_value AS sku, t1.post_date AS DATE, t1.post_content AS content, t1.post_title AS title
FROM wp_posts t1, wp_postmeta t2
WHERE t1.ID = t2.post_id
AND t2.meta_key =  '_sku'
```

How i can show only duplicated meta_values. I mean ALL duplicates records in this select - i found solutions how show only once the duplicate _sku?

```
Postid | sku | ..
111 | xxx | ...
222 | xxx | ...
333 | xxx | ...
444 | xxx | ...
```

Thank you!!

Comment: it seems you marked this question with all tags starting from 'mysql' you was able to find

Comment: Better if you can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your where clause with something like the following:

```
AND t2.meta_value IN (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta GROUP BY meta_value HAVING COUNT(meta_value) > 1)
```

Caveat: I don't have access to a MySQL DB at the moment, so this is the Trnas-SQL syntax which should be similar if not identical

Comment: you can use sqlfiddle